Process: 27897 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
I restored my dump in new server mongodb version 6.0.3 after restoring all working fine, after some time it's failed and i'm getting this error:

(Process: 27897 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)

My server details are:
Ubuntu
Architecture:             aarch64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   2
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0,1
Vendor ID:                ARM
  Model name:             Neoverse-N1
    Model:                1
    Thread(s) per core:   1
    Core(s) per socket:   2
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             r3p1
    BogoMIPS:             243.75
    Flags:                fp asimd evtstrm aes pmull sha1 sha2 crc32 atomics fphp asimdhp cpuid asimdrdm lrcpc dcpop asimddp ssbs
Caches (sum of all):
  L1d:                    128 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                    128 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                     2 MiB (2 instances)
  L3:                     32 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:
  NUMA node(s):           1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):      0,1
Vulnerabilities:
  Gather data sampling:   Not affected
  Itlb multihit:          Not affected
  L1tf:                   Not affected
  Mds:                    Not affected
  Meltdown:               Not affected
  Mmio stale data:        Not affected
  Reg file data sampling: Not affected
  Retbleed:               Not affected
  Spec rstack overflow:   Not affected
  Spec store bypass:      Vulnerable
  Spectre v1:             Mitigation; __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:             Mitigation; CSV2, but not BHB
  Srbds:                  Not affected
  Tsx async abort:        Not affected


Welcome to Super User! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] center. Here is a guide on [ask] and [answer]. Please note the conventions for formatting How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML.
